# XBox controller not working with Pikuniku game (GOG)

Tags: bluetooth, games

I'm trying to play Pikuniku on my iMac Pro (Intel) with the current version of Macos Ventura (13.3.1). It's the GOG version.

I have a brand new XBox Core controller connected with Bluetooth. The computer recognizes it and it appears to be fully functional when I [test it](https://gamepad-tester.com/).

For some reason, Pikuniku completely ignores input from the controller except for two things:

- When I first open the game and it says "press any button", a button press on the controller works.
- When I go to Settings > Controls > Configure Controllers and press a button on the controller, it shows that a controller is connected. But I can't even hit "Confirm" using the controller. All button presses are ignored.

I can't find anything in the GOG forums about this specific issue. GOG does have a [support entry](https://support.gog.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037030774-Controller-is-not-working-Mac-?product=gog) for controllers not working on Macs in general, but all they recommend is making sure Steam isn't running (it's not installed).

Has anyone successfully played Pikuniku on a Mac with a bluetooth controller? Is there something special I need to do to make it work?